# How to handle OutOfMemoryError 1040KB stack failed this error

Tags: android, event-handling, out-of-memory

I'm using Retrofit to POST some data stored in a server database to a server. The problem is when API hit  40 to 50 times then after that, I Post Code and Error please check and suggest me the right way to solve the problem and crash. Error is:

```
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: pthread_create (1040KB stack) failed: Try again
    at java.lang.Thread.nativeCreate(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Thread.start(Thread.java:733)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.addWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:975)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.execute(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1393)
    at retrofit.RestAdapter$RestHandler.invoke(RestAdapter.java:276)
    at java.lang.reflect.Proxy.invoke(Proxy.java:1006)
    at $Proxy0.getRideDetail(Unknown Source)
    at qwykr.rydier.interactorImpl.HomeScreenInteractorImpl.checkRideStatus(HomeScreenInteractorImpl.java:149)
    at qwykr.rydier.interactorImpl.HomeScreenInteractorImpl$6.success(HomeScreenInteractorImpl.java:189)
    at qwykr.rydier.interactorImpl.HomeScreenInteractorImpl$6.success(HomeScreenInteractorImpl.java:149)
    at retrofit.CallbackRunnable$1.run(CallbackRunnable.java:45)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:873)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6669)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:858)
```

and this is the Retrofit Code: crash impact on the first line. I'll also use thread and Background method to handle the app and data. Please suggest the right one idea

```
 RetroUtils.getHostAdapter(activity,ApiEndpointInterface.URL).create(ApiEndpointInterface.class).getRideDetail(rideID, new Callback<ArringDriverResponse>() {
                @Override
                public void success(ArringDriverResponse arringDriverResponse, Response response) {

                }

                @Override
                public void failure(RetrofitError retrofitError) {
                    System.out.println("RdieM Ain   "+retrofitError.getMessage());
                }
            });
```

Comment: ` 40 to 50 times` ? recursively ?

Comment: @ADM yes sometimes its below

Comment: You should not enqueue this much calls , Its absurd  . Whats your use case of making that much calls . You should look for a elegant way to do this .

Comment: @ADM try to show some elegant way example ?

Comment: @ADM is Handler or thread are the way of control  out of memory exception error

Comment: Handler or thread are not the way in anyway . How could i present a way if i do not know the use case ? Edit your question with proper details . Why ? How ? and What?.

Comment: @ADM ok only you have an answer to control the out of memory exception

Answer (score -1):

1:In your manifest application section add following below

```
   android:largeHeap="true">
```

2: no 1 is the temporary solution you have to find out the real causes and solve it.You can use a library to track memory leaks. https://github.com/square/leakcanary

Comment: "pthread_create failed" does not look like a problem with a too small heap - rather the opposite....

Comment: Did you try the leakcanary library ? its easy. it will help you to find out the memory leak.

Comment: @umer  please try to show some example to handle  the data

Comment: @MohitLakhanpal you are unexperienced developer i show you how to solve this there are two ways please try leakcanary to get where is memory leak and solve it.